# CSS cursor resolution selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

I am working on changing cursor in Angular2/Javascript, and I'm using .cur file in order to represent the cursor.
I'm using the correct manner:

```
cursor:     url(cursor.cur), auto
```

However, my .cur file contains 3 resolutions cursors (for each screen resolution). I select the wanted resolution in code.
How can I select the wanted resolution in the CSS? It picks the wrong resolution automatically.

Comment: [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Media Queries helps me declare the all resolution. I need to select only cursor's resolutions.

Comment: `cursor` css property is quite limited, how about 1 file per cursor resolution and you change it based on a css class?

Comment: So what's the use of .cur file if I need to duplicate it?